# Deploying Logic App to Azure and Registering to Active Directory Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I have a client who told me they have Azure. Fine, I built a Logic App and am ready to deploy. The link they gave me is www.add.portal.azure.com

I see all the users who will use my Logic App. I also see a place to register apps. Instinct tells me I should:
1) Deploy the Logic App to the client Azure portal
2) Register the Logic App in client ADD Azure portal
3) Done!

Devil is in the details and I'm newer-ish to Azure....

Is it valid to assume the client has an Azure subscription which supports my Logic App? I don't know if someone can buy just the ADD.azure.portal.com and not have azure.portal.com
What cost am I asking the client to assume by creating the Logic App if any?
There ADD is full of users. Right now I will have the users authenticate by typing in their email. But I assume there is a Logic App control for add authentication?

Thank you for your patience with a newbie

Comment: Hi John, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **you can't deploy the logic app just by the link provided from the client**. This link is just for Azure Active Directory, if you want to deploy the logic app, you need to ask the client to [add you as a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-guest-user) in their azure active directory and [assign a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#overview-of-access-control-iam) to you(at least "Contributor") in their azure subscription.

Then you can login the client azure portal and deploy your logic app by ARM template in their azure portal, and you can also register the logic app by [enable the "Identity"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity) under the "Settings" tab in your logic app.(the screenshot shown as below)

[image]

By the way, I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly. So if the solution doesn't match your requirements, please provide more details of your question, I will try to help you further. If the answer helps your problem, could you please [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and help. I will accept your answer when I do deploy the logic app. Hopefully in the next few days. The have added me in Active Directory and made me an admin. But I've still not actually 'seen' the Azure portal. I'm so new I don't know if it exists. I'll accept your answer if you can tell me for sure they have an azure portal based on the fact we know add.portal exists. This was my original question.

Comment: Hi @JohnLigda, I'm not so clear about your concern your comment above. But it seems that you don't know how to log in their azure portal. Since they have added you to their Azure AD, you need to ask them for the account which they added for you(maybe they added you in AD with your email as account). You will receive an email for "get start", you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal#accept-the-invitation) about how to accept the invitation.

Comment: @JohnLigda For the next time if you want to login their azure portal, just browse "https://portal.azure.com/#home" and login with your email and password. If I misunderstood your requirements or have any other questions about it, please feel free to let me know.